# Python Regex for hyphenated words

Tags: python, regex, hyphenation

I'm looking for a regex to match hyphenated words in Python.

The closest I've managed to get is: '\w+-\w+[-w+]*'

```py
text = "one-hundered-and-three- some text foo-bar some--text"
hyphenated = re.findall(r'\w+-\w+[-\w+]*',text)
```

which returns list `['one-hundered-and-three-', 'foo-bar']`.

This is almost perfect except for the trailing hyphen after `'three'`. I only want the additional hyphen if followed by a `'word'`. i.e. instead of the `'[-\w+]\*'` I need something like `'(-\w+)*'` which I thought would work, but doesn't (it returns `['-three, '']`). i.e. something that matches `|word` followed by hyphen followed by word followed by hyphen_word zero or more times|.

Comment: I don't know what you plan to use this for, but have you considered cases where a trailing or prefixed hyphen is [valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), like "nineteenth- and twentieth-century" or "investor-owned and -operated"?

Comment: The main problem in your own expression are the square brackets. They don't group the content together, they create a character class, thats something completely different.

Comment: Thanks for the input, lazyr. I have considered the cases you point out, and they will not pose a problem.

Thanks for the clarification, stema. I realised that the square brackets did not group the content, but they resulted in the closest match for what I was attempting to do.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+',text)
```

Here we consider a hyphenated word to be:

- a number of word chars
- followed by any number of:

  - a single hyphen
  - followed by word chars