# Regex to add quotes around hyphenated strings

Tags: python, python-re

I want to add quotes around all hyphenated words in a string.

With an example string, the desired function `add_quotes()` should perform like this:

```py
>>> s = '{name = first-name}'
>>> add_quotes(s)
{name = "first-name"}
```

I know how to find all occurances of hyphenated works using [this Regex selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8383339/6068036), but don't know how to add quotes around each of those occurances in the original string.

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = '{name = first-name}'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+', s)
['first-name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can be used to do this with Python Module `re` from the standard library.

```py
import re

def add_quotes(s):
    return re.sub(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+', r'"\g<0>"', s)

s = '{name = first-name}'
add_quotes(s)  # returns '{name = "first-name"}'
```

where the occurances of hyphenated words are found using [this selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8383339/6068036).